# How to get the maximum value of list in groovy?

Tags: list, groovy, max

Tried this code but it wont return the expected output. The list that i have doesnt have single quote.

```
def curlCmd = sh(script: "<some curl cmd POST>", returnStdout:true).trim()
def parsedResponse = readJSON text: curlCmd
def response = parsedResponse['fruit']
// Output of response is [apple123, apple124, apple125]
def maxValue = response.max() 

echo "maxValue: ${maxValue}"
```

Actual Output:

```
maxValue: []
```

Expected Output:

```
maxValue: [apple125]
```

Comment: `['apple123', 'apple125', 'apple124'].max()` returns `apple125`.

Comment: My reponse only returns [apple123, apple124, apple125].what should i add to add single quote to taht list?

Comment: what type your return is of?

Comment: I just edited my question

Comment: what is the type of `response`?

Comment: Its a list ```[apple123, apple124, apple125] ```

Comment: if it were the `max()` would work straight away. print the class of the list out

Comment: I printed the class and its ```class.java.util.ArrayList```

Comment: and it's size is?

Comment: I already posted the answer. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine:

```
def curlCmd = sh(script: "<some curl cmd POST>", returnStdout:true).trim()
def parsedResponse = readJSON text: curlCmd
def response = parsedResponse['fruit'] as ArrayList
// Output of response is [apple123, apple124, apple125]
def maxValue = Collections.max(response) 

echo "maxValue: ${maxValue}"
```

Output:

```
maxValue: apple125
```